# "It goes to something" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

On a presidential debate analysis program on KCRW yesterday a guest gave his  thoughts on Andrew Yang's sweepstakes pilot and labeled it a ploy. The host then followed by saying:

> I think it **goes to** an interesting thing about Andrew Yang's
>   support, which is that even though he is running for a democratic primary
>   he has a lot of supporters who would identify as libertarians..."

Does "It goes to..." here mean *it explains/says an interesting thing about...?*

Why is this not in the dictionary and when did this usage enter the American language?

Can I borrow this and use it in my everyday conversation?

Answer (score 1):

to go to something

If you are discussing a topic with someone and use the phrase: X goes to something,

It means: to show or reveal or explain something about a situation.

It is often used by people like talk show hosts or TV presenters. And yes, it is perfectly usable.

I have no idea when it started being used.

Answer (score -1):

Spoken English is different where you have *some liberty* to use the language in your own dialect or style. I guess, this is one such usage.

I keep coming across many such phrases or strings spoken by native speakers where dictionaries fail to explain a literal meaning. As a non-native speaker, I accept it wholeheartedly but then I use it in my speaking and never writing.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like the speaker started using the expression ["It goes to show..."](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/it-just-goes-to-show) but then changed his or her mind part way through, and switched to the less categorical "An interesting thing about..."

Comment: Did you notice the weird phrasing *"even though he is running a democratic primary [what goes here?] he has a lot of supporters"*

Comment: This prompted me to re-listen and add what I'd missed hearing. It actually went: _"Even though he is running for a democratic primary, he has a..."_ I don't know if this is any less _weird_ to your ears. I've heard news reporters drop _elections_ in _democratic primary elections_ and end it at _primary_.